# Lightning component redirect to URL in the same tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm implementing a redirect in a Lightning component, but it's opening in a new browser tab. I want the redirect to happen in the same tab:

```
navigate : function(component, event, helper) {
 var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
  urlEvent.setParams({
    'url': 'http://www.myurl.com'
  });
  urlEvent.fire();
}
```

Is there a way to force it to redirect in the same browser tab?

Comment: No it does not work.....you may need to use window.location...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using `e.force:navigateToURL` event, to be able to remain in the same window/tab, you need to use **relative** URL. If you use an **absolute** or **external** URL (as in your case), by default the event opens up a new window/tab and that there's no way to control that behavior.

Below is the excerpt where this behavior is mentioned in the [event's documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation):

> Relative and absolute URLs are supported. Relative URLs are relative to the Salesforce mobile web domain, and retain navigation history. **External URLs open in a separate browser window**.

If you refer to the example in the documentation, the first approach navigates to an Opportunity tab within the same window, whereas the second example opens the link in a new tab/window.